# Prove that every integer from 1 to p – 1 occurs exactly once among these residues.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $p$ be a prime and $1 \leq a \leq p-1$. Consider the numbers $a, 2a, 3a, \cdots, (p-1)a$. Divide each of them by $p$, to get residues $r_1,r_2, \cdots,r_{p-1}$. Prove that every integer from $1$ to $p-1$ occurs exactly once among these residues.

[Hint: First prove that no residue can occur twice.]

I can solve this one manually. However, I need to know the mathematical expression for the midterm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\{r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_{p-1}\}$ and $B=\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$. It is clear that $A\subset B$. We must show that $A=B$. If $r_j\neq r_k$ when $j\neq k$ then there are exactly $p-1$ elements in $A$. Since $B$ has exactly $p-1$ elements, it suffices to show that $r_j\neq r_k$ when $j\neq k$.

Suppose that $j\neq k$ but $r_j=r_k=r$. Then
$$aj=pq_j+r$$
$$ak=pq_k+r$$
Substracting:
$$a(k-j)=p(q_k-q_j)$$
Therefore (since $p$ is prime) $p$ divides $a$ or $k-j$, but both are impossible because they are lesser than $p$.

Comment: I couldn't understand the proof of every integer from 1 to p-1 occurs once can you explain it further?